# iText Irregular Columns Images and Text Wrap

Tags: c#, itext, word-wrap

I'm using iTextSharp to generate PDFs, and another department is insistent on getting the PDF I'm making to match their mock-up as best I can.  I'm encountering an issue with wrapping text around images in columns.  I know from my research that putting an image in a PDFCell with text isn't going to work, so I was trying to use irregular columns.  Below is my sample code.

```
float width = 200.0f;
float height = 320.0f;
float gutter = 3;
PdfTemplate tempCanvas = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(width, height);
float x1 = underPressure.ScaledWidth + gutter;
float y1 = height - underPressure.ScaledHeight - gutter;
float[] LEFT = new float[] { width, height, x1, y1, 0, y1, 0, 0 };
float[] RIGHT = new float[] {0,height,width,0};

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(tempCanvas);
ct.SetColumns(LEFT, RIGHT);
underPressure.SetAbsolutePosition(x1 - 10, y1 - 120);
tempCanvas.AddImage(underPressure);
ct.SetText(tempPhrase);
...
```

I found code that places the image on the left side of the text, and gets the text to wrap according to the image, but I need something that looks like the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4KU.png

And I must confess, I'm rather confused by the LEFT and RIGHT column properties.  From the book, the LEFT and RIGHT arrays define the borders of the polygon you are trying to create, but could someone give a more detailed description of how this works?  I've been trying to wrap my head around it and failing miserably.  Thank you for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out, and I thought I would post here.  I had to reread the iText book a few times to figure this out, but the LEFT and RIGHT arrays are just the points you want to specify for the polygon you are drawing to make the column.

//For creating an irregular column, you MUST specify the points of the polygon you want to draw in the form of left side coordinates and right side coordinates.

```
//Because we only need a straight line for the left side of the shape of the column, we can specify two points: the top coordinate, and the bottom coordinate.
//The right is a little trickier, but using Math, you can create the points you need the scaled width and scaled height of the image.
float[] LEFT = new float[] { 0,height, 0,0 };
float[] RIGHT = new float[] {width,height,  width,y1 + 40,  width - x1 - 5,y1 + 40,  width - x1 - 5,y1 - underPressure.ScaledHeight / 2.0f + 10,  width, y1 - underPressure.ScaledHeight / 2.0f + 10, width, 0 };
```

Gives me the result that I needed.  The LEFT is only the top, upper left point of the shape, and the lower left point of the shape.  I only needed a straight line for the left edge.  The RIGHT array was a little trickier, but it is the shape I needed and it can be figured out with math.

Yay.